# Symfony 1.4 filter doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

i have a problem with my filters in Symfony 1.4 (module created by admin generator)

```
 <?php

abstract class BaseTestFormFilter extends BaseFormFilterDoctrine
{
    public function setup()
    {
        $this->setWidgets(array(
            'country' => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => $this->getChoicesByField('country'))),
            'currency' => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => $this->getChoicesByField('currency'))),
        ));

        $this->setValidators(array(
            'country' => new sfValidatorPass(array('required' => false)),
            'currency' => new sfValidatorPass(array('required' => false)),
        ));

        $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('economicCalendar_filters[%s]');

        $this->errorSchema = new sfValidatorErrorSchema($this->validatorSchema);

        $this->setupInheritance();

        parent::setup();
    }

    private function getChoicesByField($field){
        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->select("t.$field")
            ->from('Test t')
            ->groupBy("$field")
            ->execute();

        $query_result = $q->toArray();
        $result = array();
        foreach ($query_result as $val) {
            $result[$val[$field]] = $val[$field];
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function getModelName()
    {
        return 'Test';
    }

    public function getFields()
    {
        return array(
            'country' => 'Text',
            'currency' => 'Text',
        );
    }
}
```

So I have 2 filter fields that looks like selects. Problem is that they are populating, when I try to filter, but don't filter nothing, data is the same, as with out them. Will apreciate any help.

Comment: Never write into a generated base class. It will be overwritten when you run the command again. Use the `TestFormFilter` class instead of `BaseTestFormFilter` and it's `configure` method instead of `setup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem - I needed to add method

```
public function addCountryColumnQuery($query, $field, $value)
{
    if (!empty($value))
    {
        $query->andWhereIn('country', $value);
    }
}
```

with out this method, query that get filtered values don't get values, that I need.